# Eigenvector is associated with a single eigenvalue.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can one explain intuitively that each eigenvector is associated with a single eigenvalue? 
Is there a geometric interpretation for this?... Another question, can we affirm that an eigenvalue is associated with infinite eigenvectors?

Comment: What would it mean for an eigenvector to be associated with two different eigenvalues?  How would that work?  As to the second question, yes.  If $X$ is an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, then so is $X$ for any nonzero scalar $c$.

Comment: How would a linear transformation have two different effects on the same vector?

Answer (score 3):

$A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_1 \mathbf{x}$ and $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_2\mathbf{x}$.

Then $\lambda_1 \mathbf{x} = \lambda_2 \mathbf{x}$ or $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) \mathbf{x} =\mathbf{0}$.

Since $\mathbf{x}\ne\mathbf{0}$ to be an eigenvalue, $\lambda_1=\lambda_2.$

---

Addressing the question "Can an eigenvalue be associated with infinitely many eigenvectors?":

As @saulpatz mentioned in the comments, If $\mathbf{x}\ne \mathbf{0}$ is  an eigenvector, so is $c\mathbf{x}$, where $c\ne 0$ is a scalar.  This is a scaling of an eigenvector.

Another possibility is if there is a repeated eigenvalue.  There could be multiple (not only by multiplying by a scalar) eigenvalues, and any (non-zero) linear combination of two eigenvectors is also an eigenvector.

The simplest example, perhaps, is the identity matrix.  Say $I$ is the two-by-two, for example.  Then $\lambda=1$ is a repeated eigenvalue, and any non-zero vector is an eigenvector.